# Angular 16: ngCharts: TypeError: chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.registerables is not iterable (cannot read property undefined)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-upgrade, angular16

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.registerables is not iterable (cannot read property undefined)
> TypeError: chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.registerables is not iterable (cannot read property undefined)
> at 16667 (ng2-charts.mjs:253:7)

I have recently upgraded to Angular 16 and I was using previously "ng2-charts": "2.4.2" and now upgraded it to v5.0.3. and facing this *above error*.

[image: Error]

To Solve this error,

1. Deleted Node modules and package-lock.json files and folder and reintalled it. Nothing impacted. Still getting same error.
2. downgraded the version of ng2-charts but still getting same error.

Comment: what was the previous version of angular ? based on the ng charts prevous would be between 10-12, which means you could have switched from webpack 4 to webpack 5. This case you will need to post your package.json file too to identify the issue.

Comment: there is no webpack earlier or neither now in my package.json file. Is it compulsory to have in angular 16?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading chart.js e ng2-charts worked for me on Angular 17

```
npm i chart.js@latest
npm i ng2-charts@latest
```